# How to make a blocking modal invoked with SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to make a custom blocking modal from another thread but can't understand how to go about it. Here is my modal:

```
public class BlockingModal extends JDialog {
    private BlockingModal view;
    public BlockingModal(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
        this.setModal(true);
    }

    public void showModal() {
        BlockingModal view = this;
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            view.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    view.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that I would then be able to create a new instance of this modal from another thread and simply call `myModal.showModal()` on it.

However, obviously, if it is called via `invokeLater` then it is no longer blocking.

I'm trying to create a new piece of EDT compatible code within a large non-EDT codebase.

What is the best way to implement a blocking modal from another thread like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`invokeAndWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) for this.

Otherwise, you'd have to use some kind of concurrency primitive (`wait` and `notify`, `Condition`, etc.) to have the thread which calls `showModal` wait until the event returns. `invokeAndWait` already implements this for you, though, so it should work.